# Use Javascript and Canvas to move a pixel from an image

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm interested in moving a pixel (eventually all of them) from an image drawn on canvas. This is the sample code i'm working off and i believe it does some pretty standard stuff in terms of drawing the image:

```
    var images = [ // predefined array of used images
        'http://distilleryimage6.instagram.com/928c49ec07d411e19896123138142014_7.jpg'
    ];
    var iActiveImage = 0;

    $(function(){

        // drawing active image
        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height); // draw the image on the canvas
        }
        image.src = images[iActiveImage];

        // creating canvas object
        canvas = document.getElementById('panel');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        console.log(ctx);

        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(200, 150, 1, 1);
        var pixel = imageData.data;

    });
```

So i have this but could someone point me in the right direction of doing something like picking a pixel at random from the image and physically moving it somewhere else on the page? Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: By "somewhere else on the page" do you mean outside of the canvas or still within the same canvas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "physically moving it", but you can use `ctx.putImageData()` to apply the pixel elsewhere inside the canvas.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(200, 150, 1, 1);
var pixel = imageData.data;

// You can even get or set the color or alpha of the pixel. (values between 0-255)
var r = pixel[0];
var g = pixel[1];
var b = pixel[2];
var a = pixel[3];

ctx.putImageData(imageData, x, y);  // Where x y are the new coordinates.
```

Also, you should put all this `imageData` manipulation inside the `onload` function, because in your example, the image is still not loaded when you call `ctx.getImageData()`, so you're manipulating blank pixels.

Note also that for security reason, you cannot use `getImageData()` on an image loaded from a different domain. So I think your example will throw an exception of type `Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18`, because the image is loaded from Instagram.

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial might help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations